# Python method doesn't return right value

Tags: python, class, methods

In order to learn how to use classes in Python, I'm currently coding a card game. I wanted to test the "wert_addieren" method (this method is supposed to add the value of a card to the player score), so I wrote a simple test program. But here is the problem: The only time the method "wert_addieren" returns the expected result, namely

> spieler_punkte = 2

is when I change

> return punkte

to

> print(deck, punkte)

I hope someone is able to help me :)

Full code:

```
class Kartenstapel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Karten Abkürzungen: Kreuz = KR, Pik = PI, Herz = HE, Karo = KA
        self.karten = ["2KR", "2PI", "2HE", "2KA", "3KR", "3PI", "3HE", "3KA", "4KR", "4PI", "4HE", "4KA",
                    "5KR", "5PI", "5HE", "5KA", "6KR", "6PI", "6HE", "6KA", "7KR", "7PI", "7HE", "7KA",
                    "8KR", "8PI", "8HE", "8KA", "9KR", "9PI", "9HE", "9KA", "10KR", "10PI", "10HE", "10KA",
                    "bubeKR", "bubePI", "bubeHE", "bubeKA", "koeniginKR", "koeniginPI", "koeniginHE", "koeniginKA", 
                    "koenigKR", "koenigPI", "koenigHE", "koenigKA", "assKR", "assPI", "assHE", "assKA"]

    def wert_addieren(self, deck, punkte):
        hilf = deck[-1]
        if "2" in hilf:
            punkte += 2
        return punkte

    def karte_ziehen(self, deck):
        deck.append(self.karten[0])
        self.karten.pop(0)
        return self.karten, deck

k = Kartenstapel()
spieler = []
spieler_punkte = 0
k.karte_ziehen(spieler)
k.wert_addieren(spieler, spieler_punkte)
print(spieler, "\n", spieler_punkte)
```

Comment: You aren't actually using the return value, so of course it does nothing

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It's not exactly clear what you're expecting. If you want to display a value, you use `print()`. If you want to capture a value and use it later, you `return` from the function and assign it, e.g., `self.x=k.wert_addieren(spieler, spieler_punkte)` or `x=k.wert_addieren(spieler, spieler_punkte); print(x)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `pop` method also returns the popped item, so you can just do

```py
    def karte_ziehen(self, deck):
        deck.append(self.karten.pop(0))
        return self.karten, deck
```

Secondly, you are returning the values from the functions but not using them. So do something like -

```
k = Kartenstapel()
spieler = []
spieler_punkte = 0
karten, spieler = k.karte_ziehen(spieler)
spieler_punkte = k.wert_addieren(spieler, spieler_punkte)
print(spieler, "\n", spieler_punkte)
```

I have used the same variables for returned values. You can use different if needed.

Answer (score 0):

when you do this `k.wert_addieren(spieler, spieler_punkte)` you are changing the value of `spieler_punkte` to 2, so you are not really using return, so you don't really need it. if you are already changing the value of the parameters you dont really need to return anything unless it is something that has no connection to the parameters.for example, a function that adds an extra card to a deck doesnt need to return anything, but a function that gives us the total value of all the cards in a deck would return a specific value which you would give to another variable.